# What does "a = a || []" mean?

Tags: javascript

I found this

`window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];`

What does it mean?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

```
var x = x || [];
```

This means if x has any value, assign it to x or initialise with empty array [];

```
var x = 5;
x = x || 6;
```

x will equal to 5 in this case.

```
var x;
```

x is undefined now.

```
var x = x || [];
```

x was not previously defined, so initialised with empty array [];

Comment: Edited. Typo. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (window.dataLayer===void 0 || window.dataLayer===null)
 window.dataLayer=[]; 
else
 window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer;
```